# Skyrim: CTD on save after certain game progress

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, mods

I have a bigger issue with my modded Skyrim: it seems to constantly crash on saving after reaching a certain progress in the game. This does not seem to be related to specific areas in the game, or to specific quests. At around the time when I reach level 20 with my characters, the CTDs on save start occuring.

This was the case with my last character. My assumption was that it happened because I deinstalled a bad mod mid game, so I started a new character with a fixed mod list. I am using Mod Organizer, Loot, TES5Edit to clean, Wyre Bash for bashed patch, and tried to be very carefull with everything.

This seemed to work well, and the setup with my new character was very stable. Until I again reached level 19 with the character, and now the CTDs on save start again. When I go back to an older save, everything is fine for the time being, but once I reach a similar progress in the game (it can be doing completely different quests in different areas), at some time the CTDs start again. What happens then is that Skyrim only manages to write tmp-save files.

I have read something about save game bloating, but the size of my save game files are 11k, and this seems not be to large, I suppose.

I tried a lot of things, remove all items from my character, and then save, disable script heavy mods in the MCM, etc. But I could not find a solution until now.

I don't even have an idea what in general could be the cause for these kind of CTDs on save. Does somebody know anything about this issue?

Here my load order:

```
# This file was automatically generated by Mod Organizer.
Skyrim.esm
Update.esm
Unofficial Skyrim Patch.esp
Dawnguard.esm
Unofficial Dawnguard Patch.esp
HearthFires.esm
Unofficial Hearthfire Patch.esp
Dragonborn.esm
Unofficial Dragonborn Patch.esp
ClimatesOfTamriel.esm
Lanterns Of Skyrim - All In One - Main.esm
hdtHighHeel.esm
HighResTexturePack01.esp
HighResTexturePack02.esp
HighResTexturePack03.esp
Unofficial High Resolution Patch.esp
SkyUI.esp
RaceMenu.esp
RaceMenuPlugin.esp
RaceMenuMorphsCBBE.esp
AMatterOfTime.esp
iHUD.esp
AH Hotkeys.esp
SaveHotKeyMCM.esp
360WalkandRunPlus-RunBackwardSpeedAdjust.esp
Realistic Lighting Overhaul - Major City Interiors.esp
SMIM-DragonbornTernFix.esp
SMIM-DungeonsCliffsIceSkirts.esp
Vivid Landscapes.esp
Grass On Steroids.esp
Skyrim Particle Patch for ENB - Flame Atronach Fix.esp
ClimatesOfTamriel-Dawnguard-Patch.esp
ClimatesOfTamriel-Sound.esp
ClimatesOfTamriel-Sound-Dawnguard-Patch.esp
WetandCold.esp
WetandCold - Ashes.esp
ClimatesOfTamriel-Dragonborn-Patch.esp
CoT-WeatherPatch.esp
TrueStorms.esp
TrueStorms-CoT-WeatherPatch.esp
Supreme Storms - Cot Version.esp
CoT-WeatherPatch_DB.esp
CoT-WeatherPatch_NL4.esp
CoT-WeatherPatch_Snow-40.esp
CoT-WeatherPatch_SupStorms.esp
TrueStorms-SupremeStorms-CoT.esp
mintylightningmod.esp
MintyLightningMod_COT_Patch.esp
dD - Realistic Ragdoll Force - Realistic.esp
AzarHairPonyTail 03 - Havok.esp
KS Hairdos - HDT.esp
FNISSexyMove.esp
[HongMun_Coat].esp
SexyKunoichi2ndByNausicaa.esp
ShadowCatArmor.esp
Strap.esp
NewVampChainsCuirass.esp
NewVampChainsGloves.esp
Zipsuit.esp
EmpireCoat.esp
EmpireCoat-BootsAddon.esp
Alduin Bikini.esp
AlynShirArmor.esp
Minou Wanhunyi CBBE TBBP.esp
Minou Bondage Sets.esp
TERAArmors_CBBE.esp
Remodeled Armor - Vanilla Replacer - Dawnguard.esp
Remodeled Armor - Vanilla Replacer - Dragonborn.esp
RealisticHumanoidMovementSpeed.esp
CollegeOfWinterholdImmersive.esp
immersive roads.esp
SkyRe_Main.esp
Dragon Combat Overhaul.esp
UltimateCombat.esp
Remodeled Armor - Vanilla Replacer.esp
Daedric Chainmail Weapon Position Adjust.esp
NS_HuntingGroundsOutfit.esp
3DNPC.esp
Immersive Citizens - AI Overhaul.esp
Realistic Lighting Overhaul - Dungeons.esp
Realistic Lighting Overhaul - Dawnguard Interiors.esp
Mord Sith Cara.esp
SkyFalls + SkyMills + DG + DB.esp
Realistic Lighting Overhaul - Major City Exteriors.esp
SDO Full-LOD - The Morthal Swamp Light.esp
SkyRe_Main_Fix.esp
SkyRe_EncounterZones.esp
Holidays.esp
Inconsequential NPCs.esp
Inigo.esp
Immersive Patrols II.esp
Realistic Lighting Overhaul - Minor Cities and Town Interiors.esp
CinematicFireFX.esp
SMIM-FarmhouseFlickeringFix.esp
GreenWaterFix_v2withDawnguard.esp
ORM-Arvak.esp
SkyRe_StandingStones.esp
SkyRe_EnemyScaling.esp
SkyRe_EnemyScaling_Fix.esp
Chesko_Frostfall.esp
SkyRe_Races.esp
Rebirth Monster.esp
armored-horses.esp
SDO Full-LOD - Giant Campfires.esp
iNeed.esp
FNISspells.esp
Convenient Horses.esp
Immersive NPC in the dark.esp
ImmersiveSpells.esp
Chesko_WearableLantern.esp
Deadly Traps.esp
Sickly Diseases.esp
iNeed - Dangerous Diseases.esp
SkyRe_Survivalism.esp
SkyRe_Revenge_Patch.esp
zzLSAR.esp
Combat Evolved.esp
WeaponRangeFix.esp
SkyRe_Races_Fix.esp
SkyRe_Combat.esp
SkyRe_StandingStones_Fix.esp
Better Stealth AI for Followers.esp
AddressUnknown.esp
iActivate.esp
AnonymousPeople.esp
Apocalypse - The Spell Package.esp
Apocalypse - SkyRe Compatibility Patch.esp
TheEyesOfBeauty.esp
InigoMCM.esp
XXDiguojunHH.esp
XXHuayangnianhuaHH.esp
CWIDawnDragonPatch.esp
XXzhuliyaHH.esp
XXYoulanHH.esp
tes5merged.esp
Bashed Patch, 0.esp
ReProccer.esp
```

Comment: It's probably one of the mods.

Comment: Disabling mods on a running game makes the game LESS stable not more. (the scripts running from the mod are added to the savegame, when you remove the mod, they just can't find all kinds of parts of the script).

Comment: Try this: http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/52363/?

Comment: The advice I have (which is a bit outdated, no idea if the save cleaner tool helps) is not to add/remove mods to a running game.

Other questions: do you have enough disk space left? Did you check all mods if they should be cleaned. (iirc some should not).

Comment: 11kb? that seems... very very small. Mine are 22 mb. What is the extension?

Comment: Thank you! I did not disable the mods in the plugin list for the current character, I did not remove any mod here. The only thing I did now is disabling mod features in the MCM menu like Wet & Cold, to see if this helps with the CTDs which was not the case. Save Game Cleaner does not find any issues in my save games.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The size of the save files is 11mb, not 11kb. And I have plenty of space on the drive.

Comment: Well, then the save tool from the nexusmods might help. But it is probably some mods that are conflicting. You have a LOT of them. Sadly think you will need to read all the specific mod pages and see if they don't talk about conflicting mods.

Comment: More questions, are you using a mod order sorter?

Comment: I also heard that an alternative start mod can break games eventually. But that might be patched. (I have not spend time installing skyrim mods a long time ago. But my game is pretty stable).

Comment: And I stayed away from most clothing/eyes/bodytype replacement mods. (You seem to use a few).

Comment: I'm assuming you are using skse already.

Comment: Thanks again for the reply! Yes, I am using Loot, skse, and the save tool from nexus. And I did check the mods, and did not find any conflicts mentioned by the authors. But I suppose that some conflicts could actually be the cause. Maybe, but that is not easy to find.

Comment: Welcome to the horror of skyrim modding :D.

Comment: Wow 136 mods. I'm impressed. You have slightly more than I do (116). Seeing as you are on a pc, have you tried manually changing your level with console commands? If you can say add 10 levels and put you to level 25 once you hit 15 it is possible you may avoid the problem, or instead you could drop your level lower to keep from hitting ~20. Not sure it will work, but it might, and if not it might help isolate the problem a little bit more.

Comment: You have good tastes in mods. Can you please [enable your Papyrus logs](http://www.creationkit.com/FAQ:_My_Script_Doesn't_Work!) and edit this into your post? Sometimes, this will help you debug mod problems.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go the brute force method of finding the mod that may be causing the issue (if it is indeed a mod), then try the halves method.

Disable, half your mods. Try to save, if no crash, then you know the issue is in the second half of your mods.

Halve those mods.

Halve again.

Keep halving until you are down to two mods, then you know it is one of those two. Usually this only takes three to four halves to find the culprit.

If you are using a mod manager, the disabling/enabling process becomes a lot easier too.

Just keep in mind you may have to deal with dependencies when using this method. If one mod is dependent on a mod that should be disabled...well then decide whether you want to disable the whole set, or wait until the next bisection.